# Multiple subversion servers

Tags: svn, subversion-edge

I have a subversion server in my ubuntu box. But with many projects (a big one but with 4 apps concurrently and in differents languages) I would prefer to have a different subversion server for each one, but in the same box.

Could it be possible?

Now I'm using subdirs for each one in the same server. It works, but...

Comment: but what? Please tell us your problem?

Comment: Perhaps you mean multiple repositories? And what kind of 'server' are you using to access your repositor(y|ies)?

Comment: I can't imagine you'd see any benefit from doing this if it's all on one server anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can run multiple svn servers, however you will need to have them be assigned to different ports using the --listen-port option.

To make it easy you could use apache server to reverse proxy to the different port numbers.

Comment: Ok, this seems to be the solution. But I dislike to use apache, I prefer to user svn service.

Comment: You could leave apache out it entirely. For example if you start the first svn service at port 5555 and the second at port 4444 you will just punch in http://servername.com:5555 for the first and http://servername.com:4444 for the second. Apache would let you reverse proxy it so you could use http://svn1.servername.com for the 5555 one and http://svn2.servername.com for 4444. It adds no additional functionality and you still can reach them by their port numbers alone. It would possibly suggested if multiple people needed to use both, and be able to keep them straight.

Answer (score 0):

I used solution from below post to run multiple svn repository on same box.

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/multiple-repositories-and-subversion

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.  Links can break making answer useless to future visitors.  Can you add some detail from the linked article to improve this?